# Use Spring Boot app as a dependency

Tags: java, spring, scala, maven, spring-boot

I would like to use a Java Spring-boot application as an API dependency for others non-Spring-boot Scala / Java applications.

From my understanding, this is possible.

I should be able to build a dependency JAR module with all my annotated beans, and import it in my main application.
Then, to be able to use this dependency JAR, I think I will just have to convert my main application to a Spring boot application, adding annotation @SpringBootApplication to main class, and adding code "SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args))" in main().

I'm wondering about the practicality of this project, more specifically :

1. Would it indeed be possible to directly use the @Configuration class of my dependency (or will I be forced to recreate a new class in main application) ?
2. Would it be possible to import / use the Spring boot dependency without having to modify the main class of my main application (convert it to a Spring boot application) ? 
   This is a bit of an issue for me, because I would like to use this API in the most easy way.

Comment: Why a spring boot application itself as dependency not the possible REST Api ?

Comment: REST Api is no good in my use case. The API is supposed to be used by multiple applications, handle large amounts of data, and be async.